# Qt 5.8 and Pdf.js error

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, pdf.js, qwebengineview

I have a problem with pdf.js and Qt 5.8, i tried to do the same code in this link [Using pdf.js with Qt5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206263/using-pdf-js-with-qt5-8)  in my application but he doesn't work i dont know why, qt show me this message about JS :

> "js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PDFJS' of undefined".

this is my code in mainwindow :

```
QWebEngineView *view;
QString pdfFileURL;

QString pathToPDFjs = QString("file:///"+qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/libraries/PDF/viewer.html");

pdfFileURL = "file:///C:/Users/Administrateur/Desktop/CV.pdf";

view = new QWebEngineView();
this->setCentralWidget(view);

view->load(QUrl::fromUserInput(pathToPDFjs + QString("?file=") + pdfFileURL));
view->show();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend downloading the source code from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/download/v1.7.225/pdfjs-1.7.225-dist.zip).

Then copy the entire file into a folder within your project (in my case 3rdParty):

```
.
├── 3rdParty
│   └── pdfjs-1.7.225-dist
│       ├── build
│       │   ├── pdf.js
│       │   └── pdf.worker.js
│       ├── LICENSE
│       └── web
│           ├── cmaps
│           ├── {another files}
│           ├── viewer.css
│           ├── viewer.html
│           └── viewer.js
├── CV.pdf
├── main.cpp
├── mainwindow.cpp
├── mainwindow.h
├── mainwindow.ui
└── pdfjsExample.pro
```

Another recommendation is to create a command in the .pro so you can copy the library to the side of the executable and have no problems of folder location (where `CV.pdf` is the pdf that I use to do the test).

```
COPY_CONFIG = 3rdParty CV.pdf
copy_cmd.input = COPY_CONFIG
copy_cmd.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}${QMAKE_FILE_EXT}
copy_cmd.commands = $$QMAKE_COPY_DIR ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
copy_cmd.CONFIG += no_link_no_clean
copy_cmd.variable_out = PRE_TARGETDEPS
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += copy_cmd
```

And the code would look like this:

```
QWebEngineView *view;
QString pdfFileURL;

QString pathToPDFjs = QString("file:///%1/%2")
        .arg(QDir::currentPath())
        .arg("3rdParty/pdfjs-1.7.225-dist/web/viewer.html");

pdfFileURL = QString("file:///%1/%2").arg(QDir::currentPath()).arg("CV.pdf");

view = new QWebEngineView();
setCentralWidget(view);

QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(pathToPDFjs + QString("?file=") + pdfFileURL);

view->load(url);
```

*NOTE: modify applicationDirPath to CurrentPath so that if I move the executable to another location I did not generate problems, for the application to work correctly the 3rdParty folder and our executable must be together.*

<sub>The complete code is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/44234204).</sub>

If you want to hide the print button and the open button, you should comment the following lines:

**viewer.html** [line 178]

```
<!--button id="openFile" class="toolbarButton openFile hiddenLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="32" data-l10n-id="open_file">
  <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
</button>

<button id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="33" data-l10n-id="print">
  <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
</button-->
```

**viewer.js** [line 3058]

```
  /*items.openFile.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    eventBus.dispatch('openfile');
  });
  items.print.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   eventBus.dispatch('print');
  });*/
```

Comment: thanks it wrok now the problem is, i forgot to add (file:///) in the arguments like you. i have a another question how can i hide the print button and the open button do you have an idea for that?

Comment: Those changes should be given in the .js file, I will review it. Other, if my answer helps you mark it as correct please.

Comment: @Qtfirst I have added an option to hide these buttons.